# How to find a digit typo error in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

I have below mentioned dataframe:

```
code        Num        mail           identifier      U_id
YY-12       12345      jjf@gmail.com  ar145j          U-111
YY-13       12345      jjf@gmail.com  AR145J          U-111
YY-14       48654      ert@gmail.com  at188R          U-112
YY-15       48654      Ert@gmail.com  At189R          U-113
YY-16       88994      fty@ymail.com  fr789U          U-114
YY-17       88994      fty@ymail.com  fr789X          U-115
YY-18       14500      foi@ymail.com  xr747Y          U-116
YY-19       14500      foi@ymail.com  xY747C          U-117
```

In an ideal scenarios, above dataframe should have same `U_ID` for the records where `identifier` are same, but in my dataframe because of some typing error in `identifier` i have different `U_ID`.

I just want to make subset of those records where there are typing error of only one digit in `identifier` considering the `Num` and `mail` are same but different `U_ID`.

Required Output:

```
code        Num        mail           identifier      U_id
YY-14       48654      ert@gmail.com  at188R          U-112
YY-15       48654      Ert@gmail.com  At189R          U-113
YY-16       88994      fty@ymail.com  fr789U          U-114
YY-17       88994      fty@ymail.com  fr789X          U-115
```

Comment: Can you please share data as `df` so that we can directly use it?

Comment: *"where there are typing error of only one digit"* Do you really mean "digit", or rather "character". Because `"fr789U"` and `"fr789X"` differ by one *character* (not digit). Actually `"ar145j"` and `"AR145J"` also differ by one character. Or do you not care about case-sensitivity?

Comment: @SaurabhChauhan OP has provided data in a fairly accessible format; just use `df <- read.table(text = "...", header = T)` and replace `...` with the data in the first code block.

Comment: @Jupiter: Can you please check my answer? Please let me know in case you need further details!

Comment: `DT[, if(stringdist::stringdist(tolower(identifier[1]), tolower(identifier[2])) == 1) .SD, by = .(Num, tolower(mail))]` is an option (if `DT` is a data.table). Or if you have more than 2 options be Num, could do `DT[, if(any(combn(tolower(identifier), 2, function(x) stringdist(x[1], x[2])) == 1)) .SD, by = .(Num, tolower(mail))]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I assume that by *"typing error of only one digit"* you really mean two strings that can differ by at most *one character*, ignoring case sensitivity. Otherwise your expected output does not make sense.**

Here is possibility where we define a string distance function (which is similar to a Hamming distance, ignoring case sensitivity).

```
str.dist <- function(x1, x2) {
    Map(function(v, w) sum(
        unlist(strsplit(tolower(v), "")) != unlist(strsplit(tolower(w), ""))),
        x1, x2)
}

library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    mutate(email = tolower(mail)) %>%
    group_by(Num, email) %>%
    mutate(maxd = max(as.numeric(outer(identifier, identifier, str.dist)))) %>%
    filter(maxd == 1) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-email, -maxd)
## A tibble: 4 x 5
#  code    Num mail          identifier U_id
#  <fct> <int> <fct>         <fct>      <fct>
#1 YY-14 48654 ert@gmail.com at188R     U-112
#2 YY-15 48654 Ert@gmail.com At189R     U-113
#3 YY-16 88994 fty@ymail.com fr789U     U-114
#4 YY-17 88994 fty@ymail.com fr789X     U-115
```

Explanation: We group by case-insensitive `mail` and `Num`; calculate all pairwise string distances and report the maximum distance for all pairwise comparisons per group. We then filter for groups where the maximum string distance is 1 (corresponding to one differing case-insensitive character).

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "code        Num        mail           identifier      U_id
YY-12       12345      jjf@gmail.com  ar145j          U-111
YY-13       12345      jjf@gmail.com  AR145J          U-111
YY-14       48654      ert@gmail.com  at188R          U-112
YY-15       48654      Ert@gmail.com  At189R          U-113
YY-16       88994      fty@ymail.com  fr789U          U-114
YY-17       88994      fty@ymail.com  fr789X          U-115
YY-18       14500      foi@ymail.com  xr747Y          U-116
YY-19       14500      foi@ymail.com  xY747C          U-117", header = T)
```

Comment: Thanks It worked perfectly, can you suggest me how can i get subset of those where there is typo error in consecutive 2 digit alphanumeric mismatch. (i.e suppose for `ar145j` changed to `RA145J` but `num` and `mail` are same.)

Comment: Trying to use anagram method for this, please suggest if you have better approach.

Comment: @Jupiter No idea, sorry. You need a more sophisticated string distance measure; one that penalises consecutive mismatches more than disjoint mismatches. Not sure what's best.

Comment: I just want tho identify only consecutive mismatches like RFT123Y change to FRT123Y or UIH458K to UHI458K something like that.

Comment: @Jupiter Yes I got that; as I said, you'd need to define a distance metric that penalises successive mismatches more than disjoint mismatches if you want to separate cases where two characters have been flipped from cases where you have two non-successive mismatches. I can't think of a quick method/measure to fall back on...

Comment: Thanks, Please suggest if you get any better approach.